# Render component on body inside another component

Tags: reactjs, components, render, document-body

I want to render one component on to body or any other div, inside another component while it rendering.

My code here is below :

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
import PopupSmall from './PopupSmall.js';

class SwitchAccount extends React.Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {showPopup:false};
    }

    changeAccount(e){
        if(!this.state.showPopup){
            this.setState({showPopup:true});
        }
    }

    popupChange(){
        this.setState({showPopup:false});
        this.props.onChangeAccount();
    }

    render(){

        var popupView;
        if(this.state.showPopup){
            popupView = <PopupSmall popupCallBack={this.popupChange.bind(this)} itemList={this.props.agencies} />
        }

        return (
            <a href="javascript:;" onClick={this.changeAccount.bind(this)}>
                <i className="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
                <span>  Switch Account</span>

                //so here i need to render popupview component on body.
                // {PopupView, document.getElementById('modal')} or on document.body like so
                // how can i do it here
            </a>
        )
    }
}
export default SwitchAccount;
```

In the above code, there is a popupView var which refers to PopupSmall Component, I want to render this component on to body. How could I achieve this task.

Help me out!

Comment: Did you understand the question I asked ?

Comment: Maybe I understood it wrong. Do u want the inner and outer components to be rendered in separate divs. Clarify it a little more

Comment: Popupview element should be rendered not inside SwitchAccount Component but added on to body

Comment: where you are using `ReactDOM.render(<SomeComponent>, document.getElementById('app'));`. There use  `ReactDOM.render(<PopupView>, document.getElementById('someotherdiv'));`

Comment: Can you run this code by writing this line inside a render function of any component ?

Comment: I know i can write this line outside the render function. Please read the question and tell me what you did not understand. I already mention where I want to render the component.

Comment: If I did not render inside component's render function then how I achieve this? any other way to do this.

Comment: No, it cannot, I think you not able to understand my problem. Well thanks for help